# Select value in column from subquery, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on two database tables.

Table `A` contains the name of a lot of products:

```
_id,
prod_name, 
prod_description,
...
```

Table `B` has notes (they are sales):

```
_id, 
note_num, 
prod_id, 
prod_price, 
quantity,
...
```

I am looking for some automation in my code

I want to have a select like the following:

```
SELECT note_num, prod_id, (I want the prod_name from table A), prod_price 
FROM tableB 
WHERE id_ = 1
```

But, the retriever of data is an array.

I think I missing something in my subquery

```
(SELECT prod_name FROM tableA WHERE prod_id = prod_id)
```

My output must be an array like this:

```
5  | Pink(with id 50) | 40.00
5  | Blue(with id 20) | 50.00
5  | Red (with id 10) | 55.50
```

Comment: What exactly do you want your output to look like? Please explain that clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the tableA key too is prod_id use INNER JOIN

```
"SELECT note_num, prod_id, tableA.prod_name, prod_price 
 FROM tableB 
 INNER JOIN tableA on tableB.prod_id = tableA.prod_id 
 WHERE id_ = 1"
```

Comment: prod_id is not the Key

Answer (score 0):

To have columns from both tables use an `INNER JOIN`. You can even choose which columns from each table.

```
SELECT b.*, a.nameColumn1, a.nameColumn2 
  FROM tableB b
  INNER JOIN tableA a 
    ON b.prod_id = a.prod_id
```

`.*` means all columns of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try using the following option by having subquery obtaining the value in the column. In this example project is the main table and (category and division) are tables containing name lists link by the `id` field to `category_id` or `division_id` in the `project` table.

```
SELECT *
, (SELECT name FROM category WHERE category.id = project.category_id) AS 'category'
, (SELECT name FROM division WHERE division.id = project.division_id) AS 'division'
FROM `project`
```